# Android SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

My application crashes with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    ...
```

Here is the method that is causing the error:

```
public int getWeek(int yearAndWeek) throws CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_WEEKS + " WHERE "
            + KEY_WEEK + " = " + yearAndWeek;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.getCount() > 0)
        c.moveToFirst();

    return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEEK_NUMBER));
}
```

The error occurs in this line `return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEEK_NUMBER));`. Please help me to fix this bug.

Comment: your Cursor doesn't have any value to return. check your query please else  keep proper validations.

Comment: Try to print `c.getCount()` in logcat if it is 0 means no result

Comment: Is this really the code that causes the exception? It's hard to see how you managed to get the cursor to row 0 and get this exception with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Keep proper reply from a method you can try with the following code.

```
public int getWeek(int yearAndWeek) throws CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WEEKS + " WHERE " + KEY_WEEK + " = " + yearAndWeek;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEEK_NUMBER));
    }
    return -1;        
}
```

Comment: For safety, it's often recommended that you also close the cursor before you return the value. `c.close()`

Comment: @SilentKiller, else {return -1;} -> return -1; It will be more correctly.

Comment: @AskQuestion updated the answer according to your suggestion. :)